# want to show icon for settings on UIToolbar

Tags: iphone

Want to show icon for settings UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar than text button

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                   target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonTapped)];
```

Anyone know how to show icon for settings UIBarButtonItem?

Will appreciate any help.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a system icon that corresponds to settings. You'll have to create your own white on transparent image for the button.